# Get Firebase ID from an object just created

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to retrieve an ID of an object that was just created?

```
var aRef = firebase.database().ref().child(aUrl)
      .push ({
        name: name
        lastName: lastName
      }); // Retrieve the ID from this object in the same sentence
```

This is in case a lot of this objects are being created and a retrieval of the last object created is no good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `push()` on a reference, it creates a reference to a new child of that reference. You can get the key of that location, by inspecting the `key` property:

```
var aRef = firebase.database ().ref().child (aUrl).push({
    name: name
    lastName: lastName
  });
console.log(aRef.key);
```

You can actually separate the creation of the child reference from the setting of the value:

```
var aRef = firebase.database ().ref().child (aUrl).push();
console.log(aRef.key);
aRef.set({
    name: name
    lastName: lastName
  });
```

It does the same as the first snippet, but may be a bit easier to follow at times:

Comment: Perfect, didn't know that was possible. Let me test it and give you the tick if it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Both. Thanks a lot!